# Scope with ES6 classes and module system

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I'm having a problem due to scope/hoisting/load order. In the following the Auth0Lock is defined inside the `if` block on line 6, but not immediately outside of it, or within the class. Does anyone know why??

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import { isTokenExpired } from './jwtHelper';

console.log('in');
const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';
if (isClient) {
  let Auth0Lock = require('auth0-lock').default;
  console.log('isClient');
  console.log('Auth0Lock inner', Auth0Lock);
}
  console.log('Auth0Lock outer', Auth0Lock);
export default class AuthService extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(clientId, domain) {
    super();
    console.log('happening');
    if (!isClient) {
      console.log('returning');
      return false;
    }
    // Configure Auth0
    this.lock = new Auth0Lock(clientId, domain, {});
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on('authenticated', this._doAuthentication.bind(this));
    // Add callback for lock `authorization_error` event
    this.lock.on('authorization_error', this._authorizationError.bind(this));
    // binds login functions to keep this context
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

 // curtailed
}
```

Comment: Because the one who wrote it didn't write a working javascript code. Try ask him.

Comment: @TamasHegedus Ah! You've seen that bug on the lock too! Right, sorry, I thought you were talking about me! :D

Comment: Yeah, his code does work actually. If you change the var for a let it gets block scoped into the `if` braces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `let` keyword is block scoped: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

```
let x = "hey";
{ let x= "hi"; }
```

The outer `let x` is not being overwritten because it is in it's own scope. To come back at your question. Your `let Auth0Lock` exists only in the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

The code tries to determine if it runs in a browser (`typeof window === "object"` in a browser), and if it does so, it tries to load the `'auth0-lock'` module using some CommonJS style module loader.

There are two big problems with that:

If it is intended to run on nodejs side as well, the module will throw a `TypeError: Auth0Lock` is not defined on line 11, because it is not defined for real.

If it is running in the browser, it will still throw a TypeError, because the `let` keyword is block scoped, so in line 11 it is still not defined.